# Yahoo!autos api for ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am searching an api to integrate **Yahoo!Autos** for *iOS*.  I have searched in http://developer.yahoo.com but haven't got any api.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there no specific API for AUTO search. But check [This](http://developer.yahoo.com/search/autos/autoinstall.html)

Comment: Hi Ishara,
Thanks for your reply. I am not asking about yahoo auto search. I am asking about Yahoo!Autos. It shows the information about the cars. Please check this <http://autos.yahoo.com>

Comment: Can anyone please reply me if there is any Api for Yahoo!Autos. Or any other way I can get the data from Yahoo!Autos.